# Off-topic dialog contains duplicate close reason

Tags: bug, status-completed

Title says it all. Close dialog shows two radio buttons labeled "Blatantly off-topic".

Here's a screen capture:

[image]

Comment: Yeeeeeeahhhhh..... we're _pretty sure_ that question is, in fact, blatantly off-topic, and that we don't want it on any other site. Just sayin'. (Seriously though, good catch, we're looking into it now.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, > rev 2014.6.9.1647.